# Request.Url and ReferrerUrl in HttpModule

Tags: c#, url, httpmodule

We are finding **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()** and **HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()** values in an **httpmodule**. Is there any difference in getting the values from the normal page load?

Suppose if the request is coming from a google search result, then what will be the output of those two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` points to the resource on your server while `UrlReferrer` is the URL which requested the resource.

if the request is coming from google search, `UrlReferrer` will give you google url something like http://www.google.com/search?q=[some text]

Comment: @ajay-whiz : My doubt is since i am using it in an httpmodule, so is there any difference.

Comment: @mahesh there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx):

Url: Gets information about the URL of the current request.

UrlReferrer: Gets information about the URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL.